# Limiting events with e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Force function toolbarInit() to fire only once.

There are 2 items with the class "nav". When I click on the link "Menu", I would like to see both nav's open.

Right now, the event runs twice (once for each nav) so you see the slidetoggle run multiple times. so rather than it opening, closing, and reopening, i just want it to open a single time.

shouldn't my use of e.preventDefault() prevent the function from running multiple times?

See my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzJnr/)

HTML:

```
<nav id="people-menu" class="nav people-nav">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="region region-audience-links">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="content">
              <ul class="row in"><div class="split-left"><li class="first leaf menu-level-1"><a href="/alumni" title="">Alumni</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-level-1"><a href="/current-students" title="">Current Students</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-level-1"><a href="/faculty" title="">Faculty</a></li>
              </div><div class="split-right"><li class="leaf menu-level-1"><a href="/parents" title="">Parents</a></li>
              <li class="leaf menu-level-1"><a href="/prospective-students" title="">Prospective Students</a></li>
              <li class="last leaf menu-level-1"><a href="/school-counselors" title="">School Counselors</a></li>
            </div></ul>  </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <ul class="header-toolbar-triggers row">
      <li><a href="#global-menu" data-target="nav" class="menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span><span class="nodisplay">Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <nav id="global-menu" class="global-nav nav" role="navigation">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="in">
          <div class="region region-header">
            <div id="block-menu-menu-primary-menu" class="block block-menu">
              <div class="content">
                <ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/about" title="">About</a></li>
                  <li class="leaf"><a href="/admissions" title="">Admissions</a></li>
                  <li class="leaf"><a href="/financial-aid" title="">Financial Aid</a></li>
                  <li class="leaf"><a href="/academics" title="">Academics</a></li>
                  <li class="last leaf"><a href="/student-residentiallife" title="">Student &amp; Residential Life</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
function toolbarRespond() {
  if ($(window).innerWidth() < 795) {
    $('.nav').hide();    
  }
}

function toolbarInit() {
  $('.header-toolbar-triggers a').on('click', function(e) {    
    var toolbarTarget = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('.'+toolbarTarget).slideToggle(500);    
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  toolbarRespond();
  toolbarInit();

  window.onresize = function(event) {
    toolbarRespond();
    toolbarInit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `preventDefault()` method only stops the browser from performing the event's default action. In this case, that action would be to follow the link to its location. Your call to `e.preventDefault()` is why the browser doesn't navigate to the `#global-menu` URL.

The reason you're seeing multiple runs of the bound functionality is that you're running `toolbarInit()` multiple times--thereby binding the click multiple times. You run it at document ready, but then you bound it to run every time the window resizes as well.

In your simple sample code, there is no need to run `toolbarInit()` on resize of the window. If your real-life code is more complex, you need to separate the `click` binding out and stop calling it on resize.